# How to group thousands of dates and Id's into columns in Pandas for machine learning?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fohhl.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV2E6.png)I have a large dataframe with muliple columns and rows. They are grouped by geographic location and date. The problem is I have too many columns with dates. I think I need to further develop this dataframe so that I have: "GeographyCode", "Number of Awards", "Secondary School Stage", "SCQF Level" and "DateCode" as single rows. I do not know if my data can be used for Scikit Learn Linear Regression. Please help.

pivot02.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[['Number Of Awards', 'SCQF Level', 'Secondary School Stage'], ['2002/2003', '2003/2004', '2004/2005', '2005/2006', '2006/2007', '2007/2008', '2008/2009', '2009/2010', '2010/2011', '2011/2012', '2012/2013']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]],
           names=[None, 'DateCode'])

I have successfuly grouped geographic location, Number Of Awards', 'SCQF Level', 'Secondary School Stage. But the final output is a multi index which I do not know if I can use in linear regression. Is this ok for machine learning?

Comment: We will need a little more context than this. Try giving us an example of the data, preferably in the form `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` so people can easily replicate your data.

Comment: Hey Josh, I've uploaded a picture.

Comment: Pictures of data are not normally helpful. Try something like this: `data = {'2002_2003': [11/3]*8, '2003_2004': range(8)}`, `idx=['s01000%d' % d for d in range(8)]` and then `df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)`. Is that enough to get started? If so, add it to your question. If not trying adding to it.

Comment: Hey Josh. The data is loaded in as a CSV file.